# Python - (SVM) Why is my Gram matrix not positive definite?

Tags: normal-distribution, svm, python, kernel-trick

I am writing a support vector machine with 1-norm soft margins in Python, using the quadprog quadratic programming package. As far as I can tell, by using the Gaussian kernel I should be guaranteed a positive definite Gram matrix, but when I pass my Gram matrix (here, labeled "H") into quadprog it is telling me that it is not positive definite. I am unable to figure out why the Gaussian kernel is not returning a positive definite matrix.

Code: https://github.com/trebledawson/Machine-Learning-Examples/blob/master/Python/support_vector_machine.py

Comment: When $x_i = x_j$, I would expect $G_{ij} = \exp{(-\gamma \cdot 0)} = 1$, which is what appears in the diagonal of my Gaussian kernel matrix.

Answer (score 3):

A Gram matrix need not be positive definite.

What is promised is that it is positive semidefinite.

You might want to perturb the matrix by adding a small positive numbers along the diagonal of $H$ to make it positive definite.

Comment: What would be an appropriately small value to add to the diagonals?

Comment: You want it to be small compared to your existing value, it's just a small perturbation. Try $1\%$ of your smallest non-zero value in terms of absolute value, adjust that value if that doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you, after adding that small perturbation the function proceeds. However, I am now receiving an error: 'constraints are inconsistent, no solution'. While beyond the scope of the original question, I would quite appreciate any light you could shed on this problem.

Comment: try on a small data set and print out $A, b, beq, Aeq,  lb, ub$ and see if the feasible set is empty? Is $0$ a feasible solution to your optimization problem?